# Cannot install grub - need internet connection, no WiFi driver

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install linux mint but having an issue with grub. It fails to install and it looks like I need a network connection.
I cannot connect to a network - my machine needs WiFi drivers and does not have an ethernet port.

I do have windows on the same machine and it does have a WiFi driver - is there any way to:

- Obtain information about the network card
- Download the correct driver
- Boot with a live CD
- Install the driver manually
- Connect to the internet

And then I should be able to do the install without issue. Is this possible?

Comment: Install driver manually:
I don't remember much of it but on one of my old HP machines I remember having to use Windows drives and using ndiswrapper: http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: It looks like that's doable, I'm trying with mint 18 and apparently the driver is in there.

Comment: If you have a wired option, connect it during installation and click the update packages during install and you might get lucky. This approach works on MacBook Pro and Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like there's multiple problems with this.
First, I went here https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi And downloaded the latest version (my kernel is 4.4, output of `uname -a`), move the ucode files into `/lib/firmware`.

Then, on boot (I can't for the life of me figure out how to use modprobe), dmesg complains that it's missing very specific files (`failed with error -2`). These appear to be different versions, the filename is of the format `iwlwifi-7265D-xx.ucode`, and dmesg shows errors looking for versions 18 and 19.

Go here https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release to get the latest ones, I got 18 and 19, but I also downloaded 22 and 27 just in case (I had to keep switching to windows to download so I get everything I though I'd need). Put them in the `lib/firmware` directory, reboot.

Good, Dmesg no longer complains about the missing driver, and it seems to be loading the driver properly.

Problem now is that rfkill is showing the card as hard blocked. Looks like this is an asus bug, the fix is documented here:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558

The gist of it is:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

(Or create that file and put the line in it as root). This loads the card with the option `wapf=4`, not sure what that means or why, but it does fix it.

I didn't think to look if that file existed beforehand, or if there was a wapf setting beforehand, so I may have created the file, I may have just modified the wapf setting.

It appears there's a bug report filed somewhere, so possibly in the future this will be fixed.

This really doesn't answer the original question - which is "Why does grub  fail to install". The answer to that appears to simply be : It needs an internet connection to install dependencies.